# How is a negative displacement encoded in x86?

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu, cpu-architecture

I'm currently writing a 16-bit virtual machine which runs off an instruction set and encoding I designed myself

I'm having trouble understanding how a negative displacement (eg. [reg-0x100]) is encoded in the instruction. Does it use two's complement or simply a flag?

Comment: Yes, 2's complement. You could have 1) tried it or 2) looked in the basic architecture manual, section _3.7.5 Specifying an Offset_.

Comment: If you designed the encoding yourself, you could choose to do it anyway you like! Be inquisitive, find out what works best.

Answer (score 1):

The displacement is treated as a signed value (yes, two's complement). Also, be sure to wrap around on address overflow.